# Unable to update session variable in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, session-variables

I am in trouble using the CodeIgniter 2.2.6 session variables. I have a view, where some data is inputed by the user. Then, the user can press a submit button and this data goes to a web service, is processed and returned to the same view (using the controller and its model).

Bellow is the view code (**v_index**), where I save the data in the CodeIgniter session variables.

```
    <?php

    // loads the variables that will be used in print               
    $this->load->library('session');

    $array_items = array(
        'numberVehiclesUsed' => $numberVehiclesUsed,
        'shortestRoute' => $shortestRoute,
        'VRPSolution' => $VRPSolution,
    );

    $this->session->set_userdata($array_items);

    ?>
```

So, when I run the code bellow, I can see all the session data and everything is ok all the times. My application calls the web server, get the return and saves in the session variables everytime.

```
    <?php

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
            echo "</pre>";
    ?>
```

So, I have another screen where I want to use the session data, called "**Imprimir**" (it means print). The controller code is bellow. The print_r is the for debuging proposes, offcourse.

```
    <?php

    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class C_imprimir extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct() 
        {        
            parent::__construct();

            //load the session library
            $this->load->library('session');

        }   

        public function index() 
        {

            $dados['numberVehiclesUsed'] = $this->session->userdata('numberVehiclesUsed');
            $dados['shortestRoute'] = $this->session->userdata('shortestRoute');
            $dados['VRPSolution'] = $this->session->userdata('VRPSolution');
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($this->session->all_userdata());
            echo "</pre>";
            $this->load->view('v_imprimir', $dados);
        }
    }

    ?>
```

When I run the code for the first time, it saves the data in the session variables and I am able to load in the controller "Imprimir" as the code above. The print_r shows that all the data is there and ok.

The problem is when I run the first view (v_index) again with new data, the session variables are updated but, the controller "Imprimir" loads only the first (and old) data, and never updates it.

I have no idea what I aḿ doing wrong. The others Stackoverflow questions about problems with CodeIgniter session variables did not help me.

Any suggestion?

Comment: explain this ***The problem is when I run the first view (v_index) again with new data, the session variables are updated but, the controller "Imprimir" loads only the first (and old) data, and never updates it.***

Comment: Ok, I have a view where the user input some data which are saved into a session variable. Then, I loads this session variable in the controller (Imprimir) to create the view. When I do for the first time, I can access the session data with the controller. Then, if I input a new data, the v_index updates the session variables, but the controller of the other screen is still loading the data of the previous run. For some reazon, the session variables is not updated in the controller "Imprimir".

Comment: First, I'd move the session logic out of the view, as it's not really view logic, but more controller logic. If you're trying to avoid having the code in each function that uses the view, abstract it into a function or constructor and call it when needed. If you need more clarification, take it to softwareengineering.stackexchange.com or codereview.stackexchange.com. The fact you're doing it in the view may be related to the issue as that's pretty unusual.

Comment: @Goose only post on CR once he fixes it, CR doesn't do debugging. Other than that, sounds good.

Comment: @Riker FYI Jack, CR means CodeReview, took me a minute to figure out.

Comment: Ok, I will try move the session logic to its controller and tell what happens here.

Comment: I moved the session code from the view to controller and the problem persists. The session variables are not updated after the first load.

Comment: Until now, I was unable to figure out how to solve this issue. The solution I implemented was create a session_start() inside the  __construct() in the controller and loads the data as the php session. This way, everything works fine.